# How to insert different user_id from users which has different roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a project on asp-net-mvc 5.
In my controller i can get user_id of user which has role 'Users'
Through this code

```
objtimesheetmaster.UserID =   Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
```

If i want get user_id of user which has role 'Admins' i do need to write instead above code this code below.

```
 objtimesheetmaster.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["AdminUser"]);
```

How can i achieve inserting user_id of both roles  in one statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objtimesheetmaster.UserID = (Session["AdminUser"] == null? Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]) : Convert.ToInt32(Session["AdminUser"]));
```